# How to run the same code multiple times to create users

Tags: java

I have created this Selenium code to create new users. It works fine the first time. For the second run I have to change the username and email ids. I need this to run multiple times and create users automatically by itself.

```
driver.get("https://betaxxxxx.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.id("cred_userid_inputtext")).sendKeys("xxx@yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext")).sendKeys("GHin2.0!");

driver.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navigation-menu']/li[2]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navigation-menu']/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navigation-menu']/li[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("first_name")).sendKeys("Automation");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='last_name']")).sendKeys("Tester94001");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/form/section[2]/div[2]/label[3]/span")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("xxx@yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("mobile")).sendKeys("xxx");
//driver.findElement(By.id("xxx_id")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/div/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("xxx");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/div/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/div/section[2]/div[1]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/div/section[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/section[4]/div[1]/label[4]/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("address")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx Corner Road");
driver.findElement(By.id("city")).sendKeys("xxxxxxx");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/section[6]/div[4]/div/select")).sendKeys("United States of America");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/form/section[6]/div[2]/div/select")).sendKeys("New Jersey");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='postalcode']")).sendKeys("07931");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/label")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/section/div/div/label[1]/span")).click();



driver.findElements(By.name("modalrole"));
WebElement dropList = driver.findElement(By.name("modalrole"));
dropList.sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
List<WebElement> options = dropList.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
System.out.println("Total options -> "+ options.size());

"+options.get(i).getAttribute("selected"));//for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){


//driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/input")). sendKeys("xxxx");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/label[2]/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/label[3]/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/button[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("QAT");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/input")). sendKeys("ABC");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='clubsearchclubname_dropdown']/div[3]/div")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form[1]/div/div[2]/div[5]/button[1]")).click();
```

I have entered xxxxx at some places to hide some identities.

Comment: _I have entered xxxxx at some places to hide some identities_: but not others. Please double check to ensure that there is nothing else you want to obfuscate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the users and password elsewhere and read from that file. Trying creating a properties file -

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Once you store user ids and passwords in the properties file, loop over them and you can create multiple users on your system.